# How to get sushi coins faster?

Tags: the-sushi-spinnery

I just started this game and as in almost every 2nd Kairosoft game you first have to find out how this and that works. Now I learned that the sushi coins (the special currency as in every kairosoft game) is again really important and you should take care of getting them really quickly and in particular get a lot of them!

So I noticed customers generate them at for example vending machines or by paying the bill. But I get the coins really randomly and it seems to me that they are very rare.

Is there a way to get the coins faster for example by making the customers more saitisfied with the food or is there a special time when every customer generates a coin or anything like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to generate Sushi Coins (SC), you need to use interior objects as you said. I found out that the best way to get a lot of sushis coins is to do all the PR missions and make two L shaped belts with the facilities inside the square formed by the two L-shaped belts. This allows to have most of the customers have a facility nearby and you can also put decorations that boost many facilities at once. I also use quality boosters on the facilities after upgrading the belt, which seems to help a lot.

SCs allow you to develop better sushis and are essential for projects such as training staff. A list of facilities that can generate SC are:

- Capsule machine
- Fish library
- Flower arrangement corner
- Commercial parlor
- Toy counter
- Petting zoo
- Print Machine

Contests are also a way to earn sushi coins. According to the guide below:

> If you do not win a contest, you will be awarded a consolation prize of Sushi Coins, equivalent to 10 x the difficulty of the contest. Upon winning a contest, you will be awarded a bonus prize of Sushi Coins, in addition to the regular prize, which is equivalent to 50 x the difficulty of the contest.

This is taken from the website: http://adeptgamer.com/forum/pages/the-sushi-spinnery-guide/

Comment: While your answer is really helpful I still hope that somebody can tell me how to get coins faster (for example if customers are more satisfied with the food, do they generate a coin more likely?)

Comment: Can you run a quick test and check if boosting a facility quality with items improves the number of coins generated per trip ?

Comment: So I just took a look at my fish library. I wanted to see first how many coins it generates right now. Appeal is 11 and Quality 13, so it's kinda SUPER low. It varies from 1-4 coins! I guess it has something to do with the customers... Think I'm going to kill those vending machines and just build more of the SC generating facilities and it well be all good. :)

Comment: Ah I was purely interested in reverse engineering the thing to understand how it works.

Comment: I will answer on this question if I will find out which things really matter! Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Thanks, i accepted this as the right answer. Sadly I still couldn't find out, when people generate more coins. It still seems that it's a matter of quality of the facility or the "satisfaction level" of the people or how good the food is (and when they pay in the end). That L-shape sounds good, I started my second game now and am building 3x3 belts (for one prep station only) 3 next to each other, then leave some space between two I-shapes and fill this gap with facilities. Hope my english is not too bad :)

Comment: To me your English is perfect but I am French. In Year 10 I generate over 150 coins per period using the L shaped on my first playthrough.